# What is the difference between a noun modified by of and a noun modified by an adjective?

Tags: modifier-vs-of

What is the difference of nuance between "a man of culture" and "a
cultured man"?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no systematic difference: every case is individual. Forms with "of" are usually more formal, and sometimes quite stilted.

In some cases, they are synonymous or nearly so. Sometimes there is a difference in connotation. Sometimes the meanings are quite different, or one form barely exists.

Your example, with "culture" is in the first group: hardly any difference in meaning.

Comment: Would you consider a drunken lout on a city street to (at the time) be a man of (a regional) culture—but not be a cultured man?

Comment: @JasonBassford: No. There is a significant difference between a man of culture and a man of **a** culture.

Comment: I presume you would also think there is a difference between *a man of culture* and *a man (who comes) from culture*? I'm sure I agree with you—yet something tells me there's a subtle difference between *a man of culture* and *a cultured man* (or at least between those constructs in general) that I can't quite put my finger on. Something more than just formality.